# How do I manipulate nested dictionaries in Swift, e.g. JSON data?

Tags: json, swift

I'm using NSJSONSerialization to parse JSON in a Swift application. However, the returned dictionary consists of a complicated, deeply nested structure, making it impractical to have very long type declarations (e.g. `Dictionary<String, Array<Dictionary<String, ....>>`).

Is there a good way of working with such a structure in Swift, where the collection's structure is very complicated and its types aren't known until runtime?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just grab a reference to your json data as an NSDictionary:

```
var dict: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
```

then you can reference it using subscripts:

```
var myValue: NSString = dict["level1"]["level2"]
```

Comment: Thanks! Using NSDictionary directly helps. However, I don't think it implements subscripting: I had to call `objectForKey`.

Comment: I'm encountering the same. I need to call objectForKey on the inner items to get access to them. Not doing this seems to not only pose a problem, but crashes Xcode 6 even...

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have

`var dict:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:"some/path"); var deepValue = conjugationTable["level1"]["level2"]["level3"]`

And the compiler complains that it `Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments.`

Comment: I just ran into this problem, and using Xcode 6 Beta 4 an NSDictionary is able to do only one subscript. When I try to do double subscripts to access a nested value, using     json["accounts"]["active"]     Xcode goes berserk and fails.  Hopefully they fix this.

Comment: @almel. I had the exact same problem.

Comment: Same problem too, how to fix?

Comment: I had a similar problem, but found that the dict["level1"]["level2"] concept just wouldn't work - then I realised I had used the option: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves instead of .MutableContainers !  (A silly error, I know, but I thought it worth mentioning in case anyone else made the same mistake...)

Comment: @Dean In the above example (running Xcode 6.4), to get myValue as NSString, you are forced to downcast to NSString on the object.  
   var myValue: NSString = dict["level1"]!["level2"] as! NSString 
   would work using the example.

Answer (score 5):

`myDictionary["accounts"]` might be an optional. Try: `myDictionary["accounts"]?["active"]?`

Answer (score 4):

In Obj-C we could write,

```
cityName = myDictionary[@"photos"][@"region"][@"city"]
```

As several here have discovered, the above does not apply in Swift, at least it never has for me.

Here's how you do this in Swift for accessing three indices in an NSDictionary for a String,

```
let cityName = ((myDictionary!["photos"] as NSDictionary)["region"]! as NSDictionary)["city"]! as String`
```

I hope that in the next update to Swift all of that can be reduced to what we had in Obj-C.

Comment: It would be much easier if its cast to `NSDictionary` and use `valueForKeyPath` like `(jsonResponse as NSDictionary).valueForKeyPath("geometry.location.lat") as? Int`. But also came across another way to get nested data out of Dictionary. +1

Comment: I have run into the same probelem. Has this been made easier? I am looking for an automated way to completely parse and typecast an entire nested dictionary/array mix json.