# Swift 2 : How to navigate into different level into json data

Tags: json, swift2

I receive this json string from my back-end :

```
{"exception":false,"success":true,"status":0,"message":"200-OK","confirmMessage":"null","html":"null","data":{"ID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001","AccessLevel":"150","Username":"Administrator","PictureID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"}}
```

I can easy access to first level (exception, success, status, message, etc) with :

```
 let success:Bool = jsonData.valueForKey("success") as! Bool
```

My problem is when i try to read the different values into data level.

How can y read data.ID, data.Username, etc ?

Comment: possibly alternatively `jsonData.valueForKey("data").valueForKey("ID")`. Or, make use if `NSDictionary` as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073768/how-do-i-manipulate-nested-dictionaries-in-swift-e-g-json-data

Comment: It's working with both methods ! Thank you

Comment: @dfri You should post that as an answer to make it easier for others to find

Comment: @LiTHiUM2525: happy to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following "nested" `valueForKey(..)` approach:

```
jsonData.valueForKey("data").valueForKey("ID")
```

---

As an alternative, make use of `NSDictionary` as shown in this existing thread:

- [How do I manipulate nested dictionaries in Swift, e.g. JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073768/how-do-i-manipulate-nested-dictionaries-in-swift-e-g-json-data)