# Accessing Nested NSDictionary values in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, nsdictionary

I have the following data I received from Firebase. I have made my snapshotValue a NSDictionary.

[image]

```
self.ref.child("users").child(facebookID_Firebase as! String).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            print(snapshotValue, "snapshotValue")
            //this line of code doesn't work
            //self.pictureURL = snapshot["picture"]["data"]["url"]
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

I tried [How do I manipulate nested dictionaries in Swift, e.g. JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073768/how-do-i-manipulate-nested-dictionaries-in-swift-e-g-json-data) , [How to access deeply nested dictionaries in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475463/how-to-access-deeply-nested-dictionaries-in-swift) , and other solutions yet no luck.

**How do I access the url value inside the data key AND the picture key?**

I can make another reference in Firebase and get the value, but I'm trying to save another request.

Comment: BTW when you make another reference Firebase does not send out another request. All those mombo jambo is handled by Firebase client itself.

Comment: @CemalEker Oh gotcha! I worded that incorrectly.

Comment: please check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43715807/3806350

Answer (score 2):

When you refrence to a key of a Dictionary in swift you get out an unwrapped value. This means it can be nil. You can force unwrap the value or you can use pretty `if let =`

this should probably work.

```
if let pictureUrl = snapshot["picture"]["data"]["url"] {
    self.pictureURL = pictureUrl
}
```

Comment: Hey sir, unfortunately I got the following: Type 'FIRDataSnapshot' has no subscript members

Comment: How to proceed? I'm currently looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136026/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-firebase

Comment: It is definately not a Dictionary then. Use `childSnapshotForPath:` method and create a new snapshot. `childSnapshotForPath:"picture.data.url"`

Comment: This doesn't return a value: snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "picture.data.url")

Comment: Any idea how to do this, Cemal?

Answer (score 1):

Try using :-

```
 if let pictureDict = snapshot.value["picture"] as? [String:AnyObject]{

        if let dataDict = pictureDict.value["data"] as? [String:AnyObject]{

              self.pictureURL =  dataDict.value["url"] as! String

           }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline dictionary unwrapping:

```
let url = ((snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["picture"] as? NSDictionary)?["url"] as? String
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax, that is prettier:

```
    if let pictureDict = snapshot.value["picture"] as? [String:AnyObject],
        let dataDict = pictureDict.value["data"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
            self.pictureURL =  dataDict.value["url"] as! String
        }
    }
```